# Javascript:If a div contain an iframe, then click event on the div doesn't happen

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here is my sample html markup:

```
<div>
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

And the iframe size exactly fill the outer `div`

Then I add event handler to the `div` click event:

```
div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("click");
});
```

But when I click on the `div`, nothing happened. It seems the iframe stop the click event bubble？

Why this happened and how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: the iframe is a different document, so, seems logical to me that what happens in the iframe stays in the iframe - of course, you could add code to the iframe to pass the events on to the parent document

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably because you are clicking on the iframe itself instead of the div (due to the iframe size being exactly the same as the div).

If you want to click on the div instead to trigger some other events/actions, then you can simply put the order of the iframe below the div itself, with something like this in your CSS:

```
div iframe {
    z-index: -1;
}
```